# man ignoring alias

Tags: alias, man

In Bash I have an alias (to run `nvim` when I type `vim`). But when I type `man vim` I get the man for `vim`, not `nvim`. Sort of makes sense, but of course what I really want is "the manual for what I get if I run vim in the shell or from a script" not "the manual for a program I don't use".  Is there some way to configure aliases or man to work this way, or am I expected to remember/lookup aliases each time I run man, to make sure I am looking up info on the correct version of the correct app?

Comment: If you think you might be running an alias, type `alias the-command` and see.

Comment: There's no think about it; it's in the first few words of my question.  My concern is that I have many aliases and have no interested in memorizing them or going through my .bashrc before using man.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why alias vim and not vi?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I started using vim and neovim recently enough that I don't think I've ever typed vi!

Answer (score 5):

No, `man` cannot really look up all your aliases and serve the manpage of the program you've aliased.  What you could do instead is to set up another alias for the manpage:

```
alias manvim="man nvim"
```

Comment: I don't like that solution at all. If i'm going to remember to type that I'm going to remember to just type man nvim in the first place.  Why can't man look up the alias? At least in the simple case where you have something like alias vim='nvim' ?  I might have to write a script for this.

Comment: @DrEval because aliases are shell and user-specific while `man` is global. It has no knowledge of your aliases, functions, scripts etc.

Comment: @DrEval I have `alias emacs='$VISUAL'; alias vi='$VISUAL'; alias vim='$VISUAL'` on many of my machines. Would you propose `man` try to expand these (if it could even see them) to try to figure out what command that refers to?

Comment: Do you forsee a problem if I wrote man.sh which interrogated the parameter, identified if it was a simple substitution and if so man that otherwise man the parameter?

Comment: @Fox Couldn't my proprosed man.sh see "man emacs", lookup its alias, resolve $VISUAL and man that?

Comment: @DrEval Define "simple". In my case, if `$VISUAL` happens to be `nano`, then `man emacs` would display the wrong page, and `man '$VISUAL'` would say there is no manual entry for `$VISUAL`. If it is to expand the variable, it has to know how, and then you're reimplementing half the shell just to display a manpage (possible hyperbole)

Comment: @Fox Initially by simple I just meant "a single string". More broadly, "anything I can handle properly". A single string with a $ in front is likely to be a shell or environment variable which can be retrieved and man ran against that, right?

Comment: @DrEval I don't know about terdon's case, but in mine, the output of `alias vi` is literally `alias vi='$VISUAL'`. That is, the variable itself is the output, not its contents

Comment: @Fox Yeah, in your case I'd do something like capture the output of "echo $VISUAL", like I said earlier.

Comment: @DrEval Might want to quote that; consider `VISUAL='; rm -rf /'` @mods This comment section is getting a bit long. I'll leave it alone now.

Comment: If you are really desperate, you can copy /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz to somewhere independent and then copy your nvim man page to /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz. After this run "mandb"

Comment: @Fox Yeah, that would fail my "simple single string" check and I'd resort to default man  behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use `type vim` to look up what happens when you type `vim` at the prompt. You can thus replace `man` with a shell function that checks its argument and "does the right thing".

```
932% type ls
ls is hashed (/bin/ls)
933% type vim
vim is aliased to `nvim'
```

As you can see the output of `type` would require a bit of parsing and case-dependent logic, but it is certainly not a big deal for simple cases. The alias expansion could consist of more than one word (e.g. I alias `lf` to `ls -AF`), but that's easy to handle too.

It gets harder if the alias is a pipeline (I'd probably show the manpage for the first command and hope for the best), and hopeless if your command is a shell function rather than an alias. So I'd unpack aliases and pass everything else to `man` without modifications. Here's a proof of concept (supports one argument only, and no options to `man`):

```
function man {
    # Find out if the command is an alias, an executable, etc.
    local cmd

    p=$(type $1)
    case `set $p; echo $3` in
       aliased) cmd=($(set `command alias $1`; echo $2 | sed "s/.*='\([^ ]*\).*/\1/"));;

       *) cmd=$1;;
    esac

    command man $cmd
}
```

Define this, and `man vim` will look up your alias and show you the manpage for `nvim`, as you ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you shell handles aliases this way:

```
$ type vim
vim is aliased to `nvim'
$ type -t vim
alias
```

then try this. The following shell function will check if its argument is an alias. If so, it will extract the first blank-delimited word of the alias and run `man` on that.

```
man() {
  cmd="$1"
  if [ "$(type -t "$cmd")" == "alias" ]
  then cmd=$(type "$cmd" | sed -e 's/.*`//' -e "s/[ '].*//")
  fi
  command man $cmd
}
```

A more comprehensive solution would incorporate `$IFS` instead of just looking for blank and would allow aliases that contain `` ` `` and `'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea. One can use a shell function that may or may not find the aliased command. I instead almost always do not override the default name for things, especially not to make the command run some completely different command. Too many rakes to step on. With this warning in mind, in ZSH this function might look something like

```
# test aliases, for testing
# simple no args
alias emacs=ls
# with flags; need to pick first word and hope that's a command...
alias nano='ls -al'
# and oops there's also the ENV prefix form...
alias notepad='ASDF=blah ls -F'
# and also be sure to test with something-that-is-not-an-alias ...

# TODO call this `man` to actually override the man
function crazyman {
  local -a cmd args

  # one may simply type `man ... foo` or there could also be multiple
  # man pages to be viewed `man ... foo bar` so must iterate over all
  # the hopefully-not-options-or-section-names arguments and try alias
  # lookups and all such... `man ls -w` may also be legal depending on
  # the getops, by the way.
  while :; do
    if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
      while :; do
        # try to skip over `man 1 foo` or `man -w foo` forms to find what
        # is hopefully the foo command
        #
        # TODO 'n' section for TCL complicated as there could also be a
        # 'man n' command alongside "man n expr" or whatnot; this assumes
        # there is no 'man n' page that would ever be looked up. Other
        # non-numeric-prefixed man section names may also need to be
        # handled here, depending on the vendor...
        if [[ $1 =~ "^[0-9-]|^n$" ]]; then
          args+=($1)
          shift
        else
          break
        fi
      done

      cmd=(${(z)aliases[$1]})

      if (( #cmd )); then
        # aliases might be simple foo='bar ...' or more complicated
        # foo='ENV=asdf ... bar ...' where we need to dig to try to find
        # the bar command, and perhaps other complications as well :/
        # I did say this was a bad idea...
        while :; do
          if [[ $cmd[1] =~ "=" ]]; then
            shift cmd
          else
            break
          fi
        done
        args+=($cmd[1])
      else
        args+=($1)
      fi
      shift
    else
      break
    fi
  done

  command man $args
}
```

With the `command man $args` instead replaced with `print -l command man $args`, some manual testing (proper unit tests would be greatly advisable given the number of edge cases in the above code):

```
% crazyman emacs
command
man
ls
% crazyman nano 
command
man
ls
% crazyman notepad
command
man
ls
% crazyman notepad nano
command
man
ls
ls
% crazyman nosuchalias
command
man
nosuchalias
%
```

Porting this code to other shells left as exercise to reader. Or, simplify and do not use this code given the complexity for not very much of a gain.